# Representation of anti-commuting matrices in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics

This is a [cross posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882955/representation-of-v-as-mathbbc2) updated question from MSE. I have not got any answers there yet and I really want to understand this problem.

The basic question is the following. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional inner product space and suppose there is an operator $A$ on $V$ satisfying $\{A,A\} = \{A^{*},A^{*}\} = 0$ and $\{A^{*},A\} = I$, where $A^{*}$ is the adjoint of $A$, $I$ is the identity operator and $\{A,B\} := AB+BA$. Then, one can prove that $V$ has an even dimension and $V = \operatorname{Ker}(A)\oplus \operatorname{Ker}(A^{*})$.

The question comes from some terminology used in Simon's book [The Statistical Mechanics of Lattice Gases, Volume I](https://www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt7ztwsn). There, he says that in the above mentioned setting, $A$ and $A^{*}$ have "unique representation by $2\times 2$ matrices" given by:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad A^{*} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
He also says that any other representation is just a direct sum of these. I understand that, because $A$ is an operator from $\operatorname{Ker}(A^{*})$ to $\operatorname{Ker}(A)$ satisfying the anti-commutation relations then it must hold that:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad A^{*} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}.\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
where $I$ is the identity operator on $V$. So, (\ref{1}) is basically a way of representing (\ref{2}) using numbers instead of operators, which is fine. However, the terminology is a bit confusing. In the book, it seems to be be implied that (\ref{1}) is a representation of the algebra of linear operators on $V$ in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$. A representation of an algebra  $\mathcal{A}$ in a vector space $U$ is a mapping $\rho: \mathcal{A} \to \text{End}(U)$. I don't see how associating $A$ and $A^{*}$ with matrices (operators) on $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ completely determines a representation, unless I am getting something wrong. Can someone please help me understand the concepts and terminology being used in the book?

Comment: Where in the book does this claim (or implication) occur?

Comment: For the record: your linked Maths.SE question is 4 days old and currently has a bounty expiring in 5 days. It's considered good practice to try and avoid duplicate work (there and here); the current situation seems to aim for the opposite...

Comment: @JulesLamers it occurs on pares 137 and 138.